# Import scss file into other scss file in angular project?

Tags: angular, sass

[image]

As you can see that I want to import share-styles.scss file in 3 upper level .scss files. I don't know how can I do it.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In arriving.component.scss, you need to go one step up, like this:

```
@import '../share-styles';
```

In routine-delivered.component.scss and routine-saleslog.component.scss it should be one step up and then one step down, so like this:

```
@import '../trade-in-log/share-styles';
```

Just add these import statements to the top of your scss files, and you should be able to access the variables from share-styles.scss

Comment: My share-styles.scss is outside "routine-delivered, routine-saleslog and trade-in-log" folder. Basically i want to share 1 share-styles.scss file in the said folders component's scss files.

Comment: Right, I thought it was inside the trade-in-log folder. But in that case it should be just going up, so "@import '../share-styles';" or "@import '../.. /share-styles';" @Emad

Comment: perfect answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in styles in the file `angular.json`

```
 "styles" : [
      "../share-styles", /*your file*/
      "src/styles.scss" /*defoult file*/
]
```